# What is a good way to start conversations with a girl you like?

Tags: conversations, shyness

A couple weeks ago, I started liking a girl that was in the same grade as me. I wanted to say hi and maybe start a conversation, but I was too shy to do so, and cringe back in fear. Sadly, we aren’t in the same classes together, and she is very shy, making it harder to be able to start talking with her. What are some ideas to make yourself not shy and possibly start some form communication between me and her?

Comment: As it stands this question has 3 close votes and I suspect will be closed.  I'd suggest first removing the intrapersonal skill (not making yourself too shy) and ask the more focused question about initiating a conversation between yourself and someone you want to get to know.

Answer (score 5):

I have always found a great way of passively approaching shy people (or really approaching any kind of person not activly looking for social interactions) is to get involved in something that they have an interest in and then letting them know indirectly that you also share in that interest to open up a conversation.

For instance: 
I am a moderate anime and manga fan. I usually don't really talk to anyone about this, but after I found out this somewhat religious girl in college, who usually didn't talk to boys, used anime profile pics, I started putting my interest in anime and manga out there in class chats, posted anime memes, started telling people if they want some anime or manga from my collection, and in a rather short time we became friends and to my knowledge I was the only boy she ever talked to. We never dated, she kinda wanted a relationship that ended with marriage, but we still remained friends, and she got me to watch Gintama.

And if you don't share a common interest with a girl then find one, that's how I ended up adopting a cat! My cat did got me the attraction from the girl i adopted the cat to get her attention for. But in the end the girl i ended enjoying a blessed love life with was not her but my new cat! (I mean love life in a normal way not the creepy way).

My recommendation is to keep your approach as passive as possible. Although that girl may not be as shy as you think and would respond positively if you just approached her and started chatting, but if you don't want to risk it you can always try making small talk with her, like asking for directions or thoughts on a teacher and such on "chance" encounters. You could also inquire about her interest from one of her friends.